# Linux: How to restore data from failed disk from software raid

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

I have a disk failure in software RAID (1) and marked a broken disk as fault (mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1). Unfortunately I destroyed data on the second disk after that. Is it possible to restore data from disk I marked as failed (/dev/sda1)? If so, how?

UPDATE:
OK, I've found the solution, I have to create a new md device:
mdadm --assemble /dev/md10 /dev/sda4 --run

After that I had some troubles because of duplicate LVM PVs, but with a little effort I was able to get some data. Not all - because the hard drive is severely damaged...

Answer (score 3):

Restore your backup. You *do* have backups right? RAID is not a backup system. RAID is an *availability* system

If you don't have backups, then since these disks were in a RAID-1 you can treat each disk as a "normal" standalone disk and use any of the many data recovery tools available to *try* and recover data.

Comment: Of course I have backups, but they are almost 24h old, so I'd like to try to restore some new files from the RAID.

Comment: On a side note, if you need your backups to be more current then you need to run them more often. Determine what your recovery point objective is and then run backups on that interval.

Answer (score 0):

thats possible. Try to run mdadm and rescan array. Have you used LVM there?